# Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2, error, uicomponent, admin-controller, massaction

I am having the massaction "delete" in the ui_component and it is then process  by a controller MassDelete in my adminhtml folder.

like this:

```
<?php

namespace Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial\Collection as Testimonial;

/**
* Class MassDelete
*
* @package Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial
*/
class MassDelete extends Action
{

/**
* @var Testimonial
*/
protected $testimonial;


/**
* @param Context $context
* @param Testimonial $testimonial
*/
public function __construct( Context $context, Testimonial $testimonial )
{
   parent::__construct($context);
   $this->testimonial = $testimonial;
}

/**
* Execute action
*
* @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
*/
public function execute()
{
   $selectedIds = $this->getRequest()->getParams()['selected'];
   if (!is_array($selectedIds)) {
       $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please select one or more testimonial.'));
   } else {
       try {
           $collectionSize = count($selectedIds);
           foreach ($selectedIds as $_id) {
               $testimonial = $this->testimonial->getItems()[$_id];
               $testimonial->delete();
           }
           $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
       }
   }

   /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
   $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
   return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
 }
 }
```

Testimonial Class:

```
<?php

namespace Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial;

class Testimonial extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
protected $resultPageFactory = false;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Testimonial')));

    return $resultPage;
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}

}
```

and massaction is like this in ui-component

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/MassDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                      <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                  </item>
              </item>
          </argument>
      </action>
  </massaction>
```

Now when i select any row and delete it it redirect to the error page and show the exception

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial\MassDelete\Interceptor
```

i have already tried the solutions,

already done with this process as well

```
rm -rf var/di/* pub/static/* generated/*
rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* 

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:flush
```

But still the error is there any hint why it is showing error? any typo or logical error? BTW i am using 2.3.3 version of magneto

Comment: please check an update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Add this file**

```
<?php
namespace Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_filter;

    protected $_collectionFactory;

    protected $testimonialFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\TestimonialFactory $testimonialFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
        ) {
        $this->_filter = $filter;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->testimonialFactory = $testimonialFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try{
            $logCollection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
            foreach ($logCollection as $item) {
                $testimonial_items = $this->testimonialFactory->create();
                $testimonial_items->load($item->getId());
                $testimonial_items->delete();
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Log Deleted Successfully.'));
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('apriljune_testimonial/testimonial/testimonial');
    }
}
```

> after added above code please run below command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to define messageManager and resultFactory in __contruct.

```php
<?php

namespace Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial\Collection as Testimonial;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 *
 * @package Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial
 */
class MassDelete extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var Testimonial
     */
    protected $testimonial;

    /**
     * Message manager interface
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $resultFactory;


    /**
     * MassDelete constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Testimonial $testimonial
     */
    public function __construct( Context $context, Testimonial $testimonial )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->testimonial = $testimonial;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $selectedIds = $this->getRequest()->getParams()['selected'];
        if (!is_array($selectedIds)) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please select one or more testimonial.'));
        } else {
            try {
                $collectionSize = count($selectedIds);
                foreach ($selectedIds as $_id) {
                    $testimonial = $this->testimonial->getItems()[$_id];
                    $testimonial->delete();
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Not solved still the same error after di:compile and cache:flush

Comment: I think, also there is a problem in Testimonial class. Because it's a construct issue.

Comment: everything else is working fine for me, just this error when massaction "delete" triggered from admin grid. any further information required too look into?

Comment: @shoaibMunir Can you also share the Testimonial class?

Comment: updated the Question added the Testimonial class @mapetek

Comment: @shoaibMunir Thanks! 
It's kind of confusing that you have both MassDelete and Testimonial classes in **Apriljune\Testimonial\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonial** package, but you're trying to use a different class - **Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial\Collection** - as Testimonial class.
 
Can you check this conflict and try renaming your import like something below if it's the actual class you want to use.

`use Apriljune\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial\Collection as TestimonialCollection;`

Comment: tried it still having issue,
Here is the whole grid code already there
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317489/admin-grid-not-showing-data-with-ui-component